# MVC Post entire DataTable / dynamic model back to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatable

I have a datatable on a form that I am allowing editing through the Telerik MVC grid control, as follows:

```
@model System.Data.DataTable

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<dynamic>()
        .Name("Grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
                    columns.Bound(column.ColumnName);
            }
            columns.Command(cmd => cmd.Edit());
        })
        .Editable(ed => ed.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model =>
        {
            var id = Model.Columns[0].ColumnName;
            model.Id(id);
        }
        )
        .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Data"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "Data"))
        )
)
```

So the model is a datatable but one which is a "dynamic" type (has to be dynamic as the datatable does not have fixed columns). I can make changes to the data through the pop up Telerik control and these are visible on the form.

The question is, how do I post back the entire table for it to be persisted?
I have a begin form block, as follows:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveData", "Data", FormMethod.Post))
{
    //@Html.HiddenFor(x => x);
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
}
```

But whenever I debug the SaveData method on the controller, no FormCollection values are posted back. I know I need to add in a response to be posted back but the @Html.HiddenFor(x => x); i.e. postback entire model throws an error.

Comment: I don't really think you can achieve this using `form`s. Your safest bet would be the JS API. Get the data from the grid (eventually filter out all the properties added by Kendo) and then post it to your controller.

Comment: In order to do that you would need to generate a hidden input for every property of every iten in your collection. In other words, dont!